# Next js deployment failed on AWS Amplify. Getting Error: Build Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to deploy my next js app on AWS Amplify. It failed by giving the error Build failed. **Error: Command failed with exit code 1**

Here are the logs:

```
                                 # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2024-02-18T20:54:42.946Z [WARNING]: npm
2024-02-18T20:54:42.946Z [WARNING]: WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'next@14.1.0',
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=18.17.0' },
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.19.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
                                    npm WARN EBADENGINE }
2024-02-18T20:54:47.954Z [WARNING]: npm
2024-02-18T20:54:47.962Z [WARNING]: WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
2024-02-18T20:54:48.075Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2024-02-18T20:54:48.075Z [WARNING]: deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
2024-02-18T20:54:48.185Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated
2024-02-18T20:54:48.186Z [WARNING]: resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
2024-02-18T20:54:48.255Z [WARNING]: npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
2024-02-18T20:54:48.400Z [WARNING]: npm WARN
2024-02-18T20:54:48.401Z [WARNING]: deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
2024-02-18T20:54:54.372Z [INFO]: added 545 packages, and audited 546 packages in 14s
2024-02-18T20:54:54.379Z [INFO]: 124 packages are looking for funding
                                 run `npm fund` for details
2024-02-18T20:54:54.380Z [INFO]: 4 high severity vulnerabilities
                                 To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
                                 npm audit fix --force
                                 Run `npm audit` for details.
2024-02-18T20:54:54.402Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Executing command: npm run build
2024-02-18T20:54:54.738Z [INFO]: > geneye_bot_v2@0.1.0 build
                                 > next build
2024-02-18T20:54:54.795Z [WARNING]: You are using Node.js 16.19.0. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.
2024-02-18T20:54:54.807Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-02-18T20:54:54.807Z [INFO]: Please read more about Amplify Hosting's support for SSR frameworks to find if your build failure is related to an unsupported feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/amplify-ssr-framework-support.html. You may also find this troubleshooting guide useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html
2024-02-18T20:54:54.809Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 1
2024-02-18T20:54:54.809Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2024-02-18T20:54:54.809Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the default image AWS is using. It can be resolved by using `amplify:al2023` image in build settings.

[image]